# How would I describe the difference between these particular solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

Let's say I have this equation (where m, W, B, and k are known constants):

$$mv'=W-B-kv$$

and I want to solve it for v, like this:
$$
\begin{align*}
 mv' &= W-B-kv \\
\int{\frac{dv}{W-B-kv}} &= \int{\frac{1}{m}dt} \\
-\int{\frac{dv}{kv-W+B}} &= \frac{t}{m}+C_0 \\
-\frac{1}{k}ln|kv-W+B| &= \frac{t}{m}+C_1 \\
ln|kv-W+B| &= C_2k-\frac{tk}{m} \\
kv-W+B &= e^{C_2k-\frac{tk}{m}} \\
v &= \frac{1}{k}(e^{C_2k-\frac{tk}{m}}+W-B) \tag{1}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Given v(0)=0, the particular solution is:
$$
\begin{align*}
v=\frac{1}{k}(|B-W|e^{\frac{-tk}{m}}+W-B) \tag{2}
\end{align*}
$$

But, if I had simplified the constant in (1), like this:
$$
\begin{align*}
v &= \frac{1}{k}(C_3e^{-\frac{tk}{m}}+W-B)
\end{align*}
$$
and then found the particular solution, I would have:
$$
\begin{align*}
v &= \frac{1}{k}((B-W)e^{\frac{-tk}{m}}+W-B) \tag{3}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Are my solutions different because I've made a mistake? If not, how do I explain the difference between (2) and (3) when I absorb k into the arbritrary constant?

Comment: Th missing step occurs on your 6th line of equation (1), where you should derive $$| kv - W+B| = e^{C_2k - (tk/m)}. $$  You then need to make some argument that allows you to remove the modulus signs and obtain an expression for $v$.  You'll then find whatever the sign of $kv-W+B$, you arrive at (3).

Comment: I can't figure out the justification for removing the modulus signs from (2), even though I know that (3) is the answer I need. Btw, this models the velocity of a sinking object, where W is weight, B is ballast force, m is mass. Other than saying "|B+W| doesn't fit the model, (B+W) does", I don't know how to say why that's the case, with the math.

Comment: When you invert $ W-B-kv $, you introduce risk that it is zero.  If it is, the integrand has a singularity.  You then need additional steps to determine the sign of modulus, which can be made by assuming $v$ is continuous. Initially, with the boundary condition, $v(0) = 0$, if $ W-B > 0$ then $v'(0) >0$ and $ v(t) $ will be positive, at least until $ kv(t) = W-B $, which fixes the sign of the logarithm argument.  The easier method uses an integrating factor of $e^{kt/m}$, no singularity is introduced and the resulting solution works across the full range of $t$. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes that helps. I understand now. Thank you.